# Regular expression for matching numbers and ranges of numbers

Tags: regex

In an application I have the need to validate a string entered by the user.

One number
OR 
a range (two numbers separated by a '-')
OR
a list of comma separated numbers and/or ranges
AND
any number must be between 1 and 999999.

A space is allowed before and after a comma and or '-'.

I thought the following regular expression would do it.

```
(\d{1,6}\040?(,|-)?\040?){1,}
```

This matches the following (which is excellent). (`\040` in the regular expression is the character for space).

- 00001
- 12
- 20,21,22
- 100-200
- 1,2-9,11-12
- 20, 21, 22
- 100 - 200
- 1, 2 - 9, 11 - 12

However, I also get a match on:

- !!!12

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, your regex will also match `234234 - `, and `34,24,`. Not sure if you want these.

Comment: When I run it through http://www.regextester.com/ it matches the numbers in !!!12 so only 12 gets matched which seems ok to me because there are no anchors or word boundaries specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to anchor your regex

```
^(\d{1,6}\040?(,|-)?\040?){1,}$
```

otherwise you will get a partial match on "!!!12", it matches only on the last digits.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33j13)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I am using Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/) and it is not working for me when adding the anchors. It is working for me now in my C# application. Currently looking into why this is not working with Expresso.

Comment: I don't know Expresso, but I assume that you need to set the multiline modifier `m`, when you give it a list of your examples as input. (That's the way I do it on Regexr)

Comment: Thanks, will try that out tomorrow.

Comment: That was a real face-slap moment for me yesterday. It was indeed the multiline option. In my defense, it is neatly tucked away in Expresso ;-). Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\d*[-]?\d*/
```

i have tested this with perl:

```
> cat temp
00001 
12 
20,21,22 
100-200 
1,2-9,11-12 
20, 21, 22 
100-200
1, 2-9, 11-12
> perl -lne 'push @a,/\d*[-]?\d*/g;END{print "@a"}' temp
00001   12   20  21  22   100-200   1  2-9  11-12   20   21   22   100-200  1   2-9   11-12
```

As the result above shows putting all the regex matches in an array and finally printing the array elements.