# How to match both numbers and range of numbers in a CSV-like string with regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Usually, I like the challenges of regular expressions and even better - solving them.
But it seems I have a case that I can't figure out.

I have a string of values that are separated by a semi-colon like CSV line that can look like this one:
`123-234;FOO-456;45-67;FOO-FOO;890;FOO-123;11-22;123;123;44-55;098-567;890;123-FOO;`

In this line I would like to match all integers and integer ranges in order to extract them later. It is possible that only single value (no semi-colon).

After a lot of searching I managed to write this expression:
`(?:^|;)(?<range>\d+-\d+)(?:$|;)|(?:^|;)(?<integer>\d+)(?:$|;)`

The test strings I'm using:

1. `123`
2. `123-234;FOO-456;45-67;FOO-FOO;890;FOO-123;11-22;123;123;44-55;098-567;890;123-FOO;`
3. `123-456`
4. `123-FOO`
5. `FOO-123`
6. `FOO-FOO`

Lines 1 and 3 are correctly matched, and lines 4,5 6 are not.
In line 2, only one value of two is correctly matched.

Here is a link to regex101.com that illustrates it: https://regex101.com/r/zA7uI9/5

I would also need to select integers and the ranges separately (in different groups).

> Note: I found a question that could help me and tried its answer (by adapting it) but it didn't work.
>   [Regular expression for matching numbers and ranges of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584456/regular-expression-for-matching-numbers-and-ranges-of-numbers)

Have you got any idea on what I'm missing?

*The language that will "use" this regex is C#, but I don't know if it's a useful information for my problem.*

**added by barlop**

Here are the matches the current regex gives him, as shown by that regex101.com link

and for this test string of his  `123-234;FOO-456;45-67;FOO-FOO;890;FOO-123;11-22;123;123;44-55;098-567;89`

```
123-234
45-67
890
11-22
123
098-567
```

so his regex seems to be missing out one of the 123s, and the 44-45, and the 89 at the end.

Comment: If you have a CSV-like string, why don't you use a CSV parser?

Comment: Try [`(?<=^|;)\d+(?:-\d+)?(?=$|;)`](https://regex101.com/r/fP9pF6/1).

Comment: @barlop: it's name of the group: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: I'd consider using a simple string split on the `;` and then check each column individually.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not sure of what you're talking about.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It seems to work perfectly. I edited my question after your response but how can I name groups in your regex to separate integers and ranges?

Comment: @barlop as Adassko said, it's the name of the group. I'm sorry if you felt loss. I updated the regex in the link to have the same group names in both places.

Comment: @rrauenza Thanks, but I'm currently doing this as a "workaround" and it works. I wanted to try to do it with a single regex to prevent foreach usage.

Comment: @barlop what is the expected result?  does `[0-9]+(\-)?[0-9]*` not yield the expected result?

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction for a moment there I thought you deserved a medal  but no, you shouldn't be picking up 3  123s http://pastebin.com/raw/Gbjy9CHt  after the 890 it's an 11-22

Comment: @barlop what is the expected output?

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction look at my edit to his question, and look at my answer

Comment: I am awake again. So my approach works, but you just need to have named groups? Well, it is easy:  `(?<=^|;)(?:(?<float>\d+-\d+)|(?<int>\d+))(?=$|;)`

Comment: @Niitaku I meant: If it is CSV, use a parser instead of rolling a regex that attempts to parse CSV. The question could be interpreted as *"I want to extract all integers and ranges from a bunch of text"*, though. In this case regex is fine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This new regex completely fulfil my needs, thanks a lot!
I let you propose this as an answer so that I can accept it.
In this expression, I don't really understand why a non-matching group must be used to surround the named matching groups though.

Comment: I will post an answer now with a C# code demo. You do not have to use a *non-capturing* group, you may use a capturing one, and use `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## C# CSV String Parsing

Use the built-in CSV parser and check each field separately:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
....
var str = "123-234;FOO-456;45-67;FOO-FOO;890;FOO-123;11-22;123;123;44-55;098-567;890;123-FOO;";
var csv_parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(str));
csv_parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;   // Fields are not enclosed with quotes
csv_parser.SetDelimiters(";");                  // Setting delimiter
string[] fields;
var range_fields = new List<string>();
var integer_fields = new List<string>();
while (!csv_parser.EndOfData)
{
    fields = csv_parser.ReadFields();
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field) && field.All(x => Char.IsDigit(x)))
        {
            integer_fields.Add(field);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Intger field: {0}", field));
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field) && Regex.IsMatch(field, @"\d+-\d+"))
        {
             range_fields.Add(field);
             Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Range field: {0}", field));
        }
    }
}
csv_parser.Close();
```

The results is:

```
Range field: 123-234
Range field: 45-67
Intger field: 890
Range field: 11-22
Intger field: 123
Intger field: 123
Range field: 44-55
Range field: 098-567
Intger field: 890
```

## Fixing Regex Approach

The reason for your regex failure is that you actually *consume* the delimiters with the non-capturing groups (i.e. `(?:^|;)` and `(?:$|;)` still match text, that text is appended to the match value, and the regex index is advanced to the position after the `;`, start/end of string).

What you need to use is [***lookarounds***](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). They do not consume text, they just check if some text matching the lookaround pattern can or cannot be found before or after the current position. Thus, you get a chance to obtain *overlapping* matches, and it is one of the scenarios when the lookarounds are very handy.

```
(?<=^|;)((?<range>\d+-\d+)|(?<integer>\d+))(?=$|;)
```

The [regex demo for a .NET regex at a .NET regex syntax supporting  RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%3b)((%3f%3crange%3e%5cd%2b-%5cd%2b)%7c(%3f%3cinteger%3e%5cd%2b))(%3f%3d%24%7c%3b)&i=123-234%3bFOO-456%3b45-67%3bFOO-FOO%3b890%3bFOO-123%3b11-22%3b123%3b123%3b44-55%3b098-567%3b890%3b123-FOO%3b&o=n)

And a  nice-to-have diagram:

[image]

Note the use of the [`RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Explicit): this way, we avoid getting the submatches captured with the numbered (i.e. unnamed) capturing groups and only get the named captures (just what we need).

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/UktFrY):

```
var s = "123-234;FOO-456;45-67;FOO-FOO;890;FOO-123;11-22;123;123;44-55;098-567;890;123-FOO;";
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=^|;)((?<range>\d+-\d+)|(?<integer>\d+))(?=$|;)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
var result = rx.Matches(s)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups["range"].Success ? 
            x.Groups["range"].Value : x.Groups["integer"].Value
        ).ToList();
foreach (var x in result)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I need! And many thanks for the explanations. I learned some things.

Comment: I have added a CSV string parsing code in C# to show you how CSV can be parsed. Do not forget the `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;`.

Comment: Very nice of you to put the CSV parser approach first.

Answer (score 2):

I can't easily see capture groups in regex101 so that part may need some tweaking, but this gets all the matches correct, and it captures. Hopefully somebody will post an improved answer, but in the meantime.

```
(^\d+(?=;|$))|((?<=;)\d+$)|(?<=;)\d+(?=;)|\d+-\d+
```

graph like pic added by ro yo

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[image]

The logic is,

Match if `(^\d+(?=;|$))`  OR `((?<=;)\d+$)` OR `(?<=;)\d+(?=;)` OR `\d+-\d+`

i.e.  e.g. a 123 at the beginning(or alone),  a 123 at the end, a 123 in the middle, or a range wherever.

I can't quite get regex101.com to list the matches, but the regex works

```
C:\blah>echo 123-234;FOO-456;45-67;FOO-FOO;890;FOO-123;11-22;123;123;44-55;098-567;89| grep -oP "(^\d+(?=;))|((?<=;)\d+$)|(?<=;)\d+(?=;)|\d+-\d+"

123-234
45-67
890
11-22
123
123
44-55
098-567
89
```

Comment: I recommend changing the first part of your expression from `(^\d+(?=;))` to `(^\d+(?=;|$))` So that a single integer will be matched if not in a list.

Comment: @barlop Thank you for your documented answer. This expression seems to correctly match the targeted values. However, I needed to separate integers from ranges in order to expand ranges before join the result to the integers. Nonetheless, I really thank you for the time you spent to solve my problem.

Comment: @Niitaku no need to thank on this site. Though upvote anything you find of value, which has some similarities to a thank, though not for effort, but for correct and valuable replies or perhaps valuable responses though perhaps not if it doesn't answer it.  Part of the philosophy of the site is not to say thank you because it wastes people time when they have to read it looking for content

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```
(?<=;|^)[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+|(?=;|$))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- match semi colon delimited values
- from the values it'll pull single integers like `123` or a range of integers like `123-456`

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/oL1cN2/2

**Sample text**

```
123
123-234;FOO-456;45-67;FOO-FOO;890;FOO-123;11-22;123;123;44-55;098-567;890;123-FOO;
123-456
123-FOO
FOO-123
FOO-FOO
```

**Sample Matches**

```
123
123-234
45-67
890
11-22
123
123
44-55
098-567
890
123-456
```

Comment: what did you use to generate that pic?

Comment: @barlop HA!!! I'll never tell! ok ok ok... It was created with http://www.debuggex.com the site even has a "embed in stackoverflow" option.

Comment: @RoYoMi This regex has a bug when it comes to matching ranges. Can you see it? :)

Comment: @RoYoMi Thanks for this well explained answer. Unfortunately, I also needed to separate the numbers and ranges matches by using named groups. But many thanks for your research and time spent on my question.

Comment: @Tomalak nope I guess I don't see the problem, as it appears to work in the live demo. Perhaps you can shed some light on this for me?

Comment: It matches `098-56a`. Move one closing parenthesis.

Comment: Ah yes, you're totally right it does find that edge case.